# Pyspark error: TypeError: Cannot treat type <type 'NoneType'> as a vector

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following piece of code:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

dot_udf = F.udf(lambda x,y: float(x.dot(y)), DoubleType())
l = [(Vectors.dense([1, 2, 3, 4 ,5]), Vectors.dense([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]),),
     (Vectors.dense([0, 4, 8, 2, 1]), None,),
     (None, Vectors.dense([5, 0, 3, 9, 1]),),
     ]

def finish(row):
    new_row = []
    new_row.append(None if row['my_row_1'] == None else Vectors.dense(row['my_row_1']))
    new_row.append(None if row['my_row_2'] == None else Vectors.dense(row['my_row_2']))
    return new_row


with (SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName('test_mtassoni')
      .getOrCreate()) as spark:
    schema = StructType([StructField('my_row_1', VectorUDT(), True),
                         StructField('my_row_2', VectorUDT(), True)])

    df = spark.createDataFrame(l, schema)
    rdd = df.rdd
    rdd = rdd.map(finish)

    out_schema = StructType([StructField('my_row_1', VectorUDT(), True),
                             StructField('my_row_2', VectorUDT(), True)])
    fdf = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema=out_schema)

    fdf = fdf.withColumn('row_sim', F.when(((F.col('my_row_1').isNull()) |
                                            (F.col('my_row_2').isNull())),
                                       np.nan).otherwise(dot_udf(fdf.my_row_1, fdf.my_row_2))
                     )
    fdf.show()
```

It fails with the following TypeError on the last command:

```
TypeError: Cannot treat type <type 'NoneType'> as a vector
```

Does someone know how to fix it? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to filter out `None`s from `row['my_row_1']`? The `finish` function is returning a list that may have `None`s in it.

Comment: I don't want to filter `None`s out. This is just a sample data set but in reality I have more columns and I don't want to remove entries from the data frame just because I find a `None` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you have called the `udf` function in `otherwise` part but the fact is that every row is being passed to the `udf` function. So **the problem is that you are combining *column-wise* function (`when/otherwise`) with *row-wise* function (`udf`)**

The solution is to move the `when/otherwise` part inside `udf` function as

```
def dotProduct(x, y):
    if(x == None or y == None):
        return np.nan
    else:
        return float(x.dot(y))

dot_udf = F.udf(lambda x,y: dotProduct(x, y), DoubleType())
```

and then call the `udf` function *independently* as

```
fdf = fdf.withColumn('row_sim', dot_udf(fdf.my_row_1, fdf.my_row_2))
fdf.show()
```

which should give you the correct result without errors as

```
+--------------------+--------------------+-------+
|            my_row_1|            my_row_2|row_sim|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------+
|[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,...|[5.0,4.0,3.0,2.0,...|   35.0|
|[0.0,4.0,8.0,2.0,...|                null|    NaN|
|                null|[5.0,0.0,3.0,9.0,...|    NaN|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: I wasn't aware about that issue. Thank you very much, your solution fixed my problem perfectly!